# OnItemChanged not called when trying to implement VirtualizingPanel in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to implement my own VirtualWrapPanel in WPF.

I implement it this way :

```
public class VirtualWrapPanel : VirtualizingPanel, IScrollInfo
    {

         ....

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    base.RemoveInternalChildRange(args.Position.Index, args.ItemUICount);
                    return;
            }
        }

}
```

but the OnItemsChanged method is never called causing the control not to release the objects...
Any idea ?
Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Does your ItemsSource implement INotifyCollectionChanged? The easiest way to do that would to make it an ObservableCollection